# Solve One Equation Multiple times

Tags: matlab, for-loop, linear-equation

I have 50 observations as rows and columns with variable values. For each observation, I use `fsolve` to solve for the unknown variable `q_iz`. I'm trying to use LOOP. I have solved it for 1<sup>st</sup> row but MATLAB throws an error when it is going to 2<sup>nd</sup> row. Also, I want to store the solved value of `k` in `(50,1)` dimension.

I'm presenting a simpler code to represent the problem as follows:

```
 global price gnw dataq_izc(c) c

price = ones(50,2);
gnw = ones(50,2,2);
dataq_izc = 0.20*ones(50,1);

k0 = 0.1+ zeros(50,1);
for c = 1:50
options=optimset('Display','notify','MaxFunEvals',10^7,'TolX',1e-8,'TolFun',1e-6,'MaxIter',10^5);
% Solve 
k = fzero(@qiz,k0(c,1),options);
fprintf('Quantity\n');
disp(k);
end;
```

And the script 'qiz' is:

```
function F = qiz(k)

global price gnw dataq_izc(c) c

q_iz = zeros(50,2,2);
i = 1.;
while i < 3
    z = 1.;
    while z < 3
    q_iz(c,i,z) = k(c,1)*price(c,z)/gnw(c,i,z);
    z = z + 1.;
    end
i = i + 1.;
end;

q_izc = zeros(50);
c = 1.;
while c < 51;
i = 1.;
while i < 3
    z = 1.;
    while z < 3
    q_izc(c) = q_izc(c)  + q_iz(c,i,z);
    z = z + 1.;
    end
i = i + 1.;
end;
c = c + 1.;
end

F = q_izc(c) - dataq_izc(c,1);
```

when i run this code, it is solved for first row but it is throwing error when it is going to second row as:

> FZERO cannot continue because user supplied function_handle ==> qiz
>   failed with the error below. Attempted to access k(2,1); index out of
>   bounds because numel(k)=1.

Comment: Can you post some example data for the global variables?

Comment: The purpose of statement 'global' is to call the parameters from 'main' file to script 'qiz'. So global ..........  will also be there in the 'main' file... is that what you are asking?

Comment: No; we don't know the value of, for example, `price`, so we can't actually run this code to reproduce the problem. Can you post some example data, so that we can just copy paste and run?

Comment: i have put the values of the global variables.. Let me know if its ok now

Comment: The error is because you are passing `k0(c,1)` to the function `qiz` in your call to `fzero`.  This is a single value of the `k0` vector.  In the function `qiz` you are asking for the cth entry.  There is only 1 entry.  Remove all the references to `k(c...` in that function.

Comment: According to your suggestion, i changed k(c,1) to k in script 'qiz'. But the problem still exist. I also tried to remove k0(c,1) to k0.But there is still some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passed a scalar `k0(c,1)` to your function `qiz`.  In that function you try to access `k(c,1)` and get the error stating as much.

> FZERO cannot continue because user supplied function_handle ==> qiz failed with the error below. Attempted to access k(2,1); index out of bounds because numel(k)=1.

The error is telling you that `k` is a scalar with `numel(k)=1`.  That is the first error.  The second is that within the function `qiz` you are reassigning the value of `c`.  You defined `c` as `global` and then use it as the index in the second loop.  When `qiz` ends the value for `c` is now 51.  That is out of bounds for the `k0` vector.  Try to always use variable names that mean something to avoid this error.

Here is a working (error free) version.

```
function k = Test(  )

global c price gnw dataq_izc

price = ones(50,2);
gnw = ones(50,2,2);
dataq_izc = 0.20*ones(50,1);

k0 = 0.1+ zeros(50,1);
k = size(k0);
for c = 1:50
options=optimset('Display','notify','MaxFunEvals',10^7,'TolX',1e-8,'TolFun',1e-6,'MaxIter',10^5);
% Solve 
k(c) = fzero(@qiz,k0(c),options);
fprintf('Quantity: %f\n', k(c));
end

end


function F = qiz(k)

global c price gnw dataq_izc

q_iz = zeros(50,2,2);
i = 1.;
while i < 3
    z = 1.;
    while z < 3
        q_iz(c,i,z) = k*price(c,z)/gnw(c,i,z);
        z = z + 1.;
    end
    i = i + 1.;
end;

q_izc = zeros(50);
c2 = 1.;
while c2 < 51;
    i = 1.;
    while i < 3
        z = 1.;
        while z < 3
            q_izc(c2) = q_izc(c2) + q_iz(c2,i,z);
            z = z + 1.;
        end
        i = i + 1.;
    end;
    c2 = c2 + 1.;
end

F = q_izc(c) - dataq_izc(c,1);

end
```